# showing video inside datatables

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

I have a problem with showing video using , this video must be shown dynamically using ajax inside data tables. Video can show if I using static src but I want it dynamically according to the rows.

in my code here, it is still static, and I want dynamically according to the row.

```
{"data":"subcourse_order_id"},
{"data":"sub_course_detail_name"},
{
    "render": function (data) {
    return '  <video width="160" height="120" controls>\n' +
 <source src="{{asset('videos/courses/Perang antar saudara - Pdt. Petrus Agung.mp4')}}" >\n' +' </video>';
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The `asset`-function is part of Laravel and is only available inside php or the server-side templating-engine. DataTables is a javscript/jQuery library that runs in the browser, because of that the `asset`-function is not available to the datatable-object at runtime.

Assuming `data` for that column is the path and filename to your resource, you could prepend the domain and path to the assets folder by using `env('ASSET_URL')`.

```
{"data":"subcourse_order_id"},
{"data":"sub_course_detail_name"},
{
  "render": function (data) {
    return '<video width="160" height="120" controls><source src="{{ env('ASSET_URL') }}' + data + '"></video>';
  }
},
```

Another option would be to fill the column-data with the complete url inside Laravel.